$\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{n = 0}}^{\infty }{a}_{n}{z}^{n}$ is convergent on $\partial B\left( {0, R}\right) \setminus \{ R\}$

Let postive sequence $\left\{  {a}_{n}\right\}$ be decresing to $0$. How to prove that  $\mathop{\sum }\limits_{{n = 0}}^{\infty }{a}_{n}{z}^{n}$ is convergen on  $\partial B\left( {0, R}\right)  \setminus  \{ R\}$, where $R$ is the radius of convergence.

In the real case and $R=1$, we can use Leibniz. What if $R>1$?
Let $z=Re^{i\tau}$, $0<\tau<2\pi$, then $a_nz^n=a_nR^n \cdot e^{in\tau}$, how to treat $a_nR^n$?

Note that if $R>1$ the result may not hold - for example with $R=2$ we can take $a_n=n/2^n$ which is decreasing to $0$ but clearly $a_n2^n\alpha$ doesn't converge to zero for any $|\alpha|=1$ so the series cannot converge at any point on the circle of radius $2$
